# setText base adapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have segmented radio buttons in my base adapter. I have tried to set text when the user clicks on these buttons but it doesn't work. I got null pointer exception but I have used Toast message to show the values and it's working.

full base adapter

```java
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private boolean[] expandedView;

    private List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist2 = null;
    private ArrayList<AnywallPost> arraylist;
    int mSelectedPos = -1;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist2) {
        this.context = context;
        this.AnywallPostlist2 = AnywallPostlist2;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<AnywallPost>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(AnywallPostlist2);
        this.expandedView = new boolean[AnywallPostlist2.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView Name;
        ImageView falg;

        TextView TVal;
        SegmentedGroup segmented;
        // TextView book1;
        RadioButton b1;
        RadioButton b2;
        RadioButton b3;
        TextView lt1;
        TextView lt2;
        TextView lt3;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return AnywallPostlist2.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return AnywallPostlist2.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2; // brief & expanded
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return expandedView[position] ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            int layout = 0;
            switch (getItemViewType(position)) {

            case 0:
                layout = R.layout.custum_alertitem;
                break;
            case 1:
                layout = R.layout.custum_alertitem2;
                break;

            }

            view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

            switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                holder.Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewserviceName);

                holder.falg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewserviceImg);

                break;
            case 1:
                holder.Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewserviceName);

                holder.falg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewserviceImg);

                holder.TVal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewValue);
                holder.segmented = (SegmentedGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.segmentedmode);


                holder.lt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewlate1);
                holder.lt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewlate2);
                holder.lt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewlate3);

                break;

            }

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // because the view type is determined by expandedView[position],
            // the correct layout will be recycled here
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {

        case 0:
            holder.Name.setText(AnywallPostlist2.get(position).get("name").toString());

            String st = AnywallPostlist2.get(position).get("status").toString().trim();


            if (st.equals("true"))

            {
                holder.falg.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);

            } else {
                holder.falg.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            }

            break;

        case 1:
            holder.Name.setText(AnywallPostlist2.get(position).get("name").toString());

            String st = AnywallPostlist2.get(position).get("status").toString().trim();


            if (st.equals("true"))

            {
                holder.falg.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);

            } else {
                holder.falg.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            }

            break;


            holder.segmented.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int id = view.getId();
                    switch (id) {

                    case R.id.button31:
                        if (mSelectedPos != position) {
                            // holder.tvMsg.setColor(Color.RED);

                            holder.TVal.setText("1");
                        }

                        break;
                    case R.id.button32:
                        if (mSelectedPos != position) {
                            holder.TVal.setText("2");
                        }

                        break;

                    case R.id.button33:
                        if (mSelectedPos != position) {
                            holder.TVal.setText("3");
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }

            });

            break;
        }

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (expandedView[position]) {
                    // this is expanded view so toggle it back to brief view
                    expandedView[position] = false;

                } else {
                    // clear any expanded views elsewhere
                    expandedView = new boolean[AnywallPostlist2.size()];
                    // toggle brief view to expanded
                    expandedView[position] = true;
                }

                MyAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put the full BaseAdapter please?

Comment: @Skizo would you check it please , I got this error message at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:172)

Comment: Can you fix the code please, it's imspossible to read it properly...

Comment: maybe you can't use if(view != null).because 2 type view has diferent childview .holder.TVal is not valued in case 0.

Comment: @tinysunlight ya I have to layouts in which Tval in the second one , any suggestion ?!

Comment: if you use different view , you should use different viewholder .and when you getTag , you are able to know  which type view it is .I haven't used listview for a longtime ,I can't give you bright advice.